# rake aborted! undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a problems with launching rails project. My environtment:

```
rails -v
2.3.2
ruby -v 
1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-darwin11.4.2]
gem -v 
1.8.6
```

When I try to start rails:

```
$ script/server
/Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/commands/server.rb:1
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/bmalets/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Help me to solve this problem, please.

When I try to install gems, I have:

```
$ rake gems:install
(in /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/myapp)
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
```

Comment: Your version of Rails is hopelessly out of date. I don't know what guide you're following, but I'd find one for Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Thanks, I know about uptodate rails versions :) Now I'm upgrading old rails project to new rails, and trying launch up it to understand functionality

Comment: Give me please guide for rails_3, which you found. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall rubygems and it help.